# How to access the UIPrintInteractionController class with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, airprint

I'm trying to implement AirPrint printing and need to instantiate `UIPrintInteractionController`. However, I can't seem to get it to find the class. How can I access this UIKit class from NativeScript?

```
function findPrinter() {
    var printController = UIPrintInteractionController.new();
    console.log(printController);
}
exports.findPrinter = findPrinter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax for your case :

```
function findPrinter() {
    var printController = UIPrintInteractionController;
    console.log(printController.isPrintingAvailable());
}
exports.findPrinter = findPrinter;
```

Here are some more example for Objective-C to JS based on the {N} documenation

**Objective-C** code

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Class buttonClass = [UIButton class];
UIButton * button = [[buttonClass alloc] init];
[array setObject: buttonClass atIndex: 0];
[array setObject: button atIndex: 1];
```

**NativeScript** code

```
var array = new NSMutableArray();
var buttonClass = UIButton;
var button = new buttonClass();
array.setObjectAtIndex(buttonClass, 0);
array.setObjectAdIndex(button, 1);
```

More details can be found at [NativeScript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview.html)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks so much!