# How to Display the Printer Picker in NativeScript on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, nativescript

I am unable to display the Printer Picker in NativeScript after calling the `UIPrinterPickerController`.

Here is my code:

```
var printPicker = UIPrinterPickerController.printerPickerControllerWithInitiallySelectedPrinter(null);
console.log("printPicker: " + printPicker);
var found = printPicker.presentAnimatedCompletionHandler(false, function(printerPicker, userDidSelect, error) {
    if (error != null) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    }
    console.log("printerPicker: " + printerPicker);
    console.log("userDidSelect: " + userDidSelect);
});
console.log("found: " + found);
```

And here is the output:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:16:16: printPicker: <UIPrinterPickerController: 0x146e948b0>
2016-04-22 15:19:17.101 checkInApp[349:41167] WARNING: Calling -[UIPrinterPickerController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:24:16: found: true
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:16:16: printPicker: <UIPrinterPickerController: 0x146e948b0>
2016-04-22 15:19:19.627 checkInApp[349:41167] WARNING: Calling -[UIPrinterPickerController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:24:16: found: false
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:21:20: printerPicker: <UIPrinterPickerController: 0x146e948b0>
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/main/main-page.js:22:20: userDidSelect: false
```

After receiving an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789670/844726) about how to call this in NativeScript, I can verify that my callback indeed runs. However, if I tap the button that runs the above code once, the callback doesn't fire (I'm assuming this is the point that the Picker should display.); then, if I tap it again, the callback fires with `userDidSelect` being false.

I've read that you can control the display of the picker with a subclass to `printerPickerControllerParentViewController`, but I thought that it would default to just showing the picker from the main view.

How can I display the picker from within NativeScript?

**UPDATE**

It seems to work fine on the iOS Simulator with PrinterSimulator running.

**UPDATE 2**

Actually, it is working on the iPhone 6 simulator. It is not working on the iPad simulator or the actual iPad device. I think I read somewhere that the picker needs to be opened as a PopOver, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue is that you have to open the `UIPrinterPickerController` in a popover on the iPad. So we need to detect the device the app is running on and call the appropriate method. Here is how that is done:

```
if ( ! UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    printPicker.presentAnimatedCompletionHandler(false, completionHandler);
} else {
    printPicker.presentFromRectInViewAnimatedCompletionHandler(view.frame, view, false, completionHandler);
}
```

<strike>I'm still looking for a reference to the `view` and `view.frame` - I have an [open question here for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36812469/844726).</strike>

**UPDATE**

[The answer for the reference to the correct parameters is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36833361/844726). Basically, in the `loaded` handler, you get a reference to the `view` with `args.object.ios.view`.