# How to get reference to self.view and self.view.frame in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, nativescript

I am trying to call the UIPrinterPickerController in NativeScript on an iPad. I've tracked down the call that I need to make and it is here:

```
UIPrinterPickerController.presentFromRectInViewAnimatedCompletionHandler(rect: CGRect, view: UIView, animated: boolean, completion: (arg1: UIPrinterPickerController, arg2: boolean, arg3: NSError) => void): boolean;
```

In the examples I've seen the `rect` param is a reference to `self.view.frame` and the `view` param is a reference to `self.view`. How do I find those references in NativeScript? I've tried the `ui.view` module and that doesn't work. I've tried `args.object` from the `pageLoaded` event and that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// My code here
if ( ! UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    found = printPicker.presentAnimatedCompletionHandler(false, completionHandler);
} else {
    found = printPicker.presentFromRectInViewAnimatedCompletionHandler(view.frame, view, false, completionHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close; the UIView for the Page; would be:

```
var pageLoaded = function(args) {
  var page = args.object;  // Get the NativeScript Page object
  var uiView = page.ios;   // Get the underlying iOS native Control
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! This led me to my answer. However, `page.ios` was giving me an instance of `UIViewController` - so I just had to do `uiView.view` and `uiView.view.frame`.